# Grunt uglifym - call stack size exceeded

Tags: gruntjs

I am trying to use uglify with grunt to concat and minify some files. I have already used the npm to `install grunt-contrib-uglify`.

I have the following in my **grunt.js** file: (I have removed some other tasks for anonymity)

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  'use strict';      

    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');

    uglify: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: 'app/map/source-map.js'
        },
        files: {
            'app/dist/sourcefiles.min.js': [
                'app/test_js/test.js'
              ]
        }
    }
```

};

I then run:

```
grunt uglify
```

but I keep getting the following error:

```
Warning: Maximum call stack size exceeded Use --force to continue.
```

If I use force, the grunt task never stops running.

Can someone tell me where I am going wrong? I am tearing my hair out on this one.

Comment: I got this. I was automating the task and then calling it, creating a loop.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem, using an other Grunt plugin called recess.
The error message was not explicit.

```
Warning: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined Use --force to continue.
```

But the verbose mode showed that my task was called hundred of times.
The problem was that I created a "cyclic dependency" (causing an infinite loop) when I registered my task.

```
grunt.registerTask('recess', ['recess']); //does not work => cyclic dependency!
```

The first parameter of registerTask method is an **"alias task"** and has to be different from the task names defined in the second parameter.
I corrected like this:

```
grunt.registerTask('my-recess-task', ['recess']);
```

And I runned the task calling this (in the Command prompt window)

```
grunt my-recess-task
```

And then it was OK!

More about registerTask() method, from grunt API:
http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#grunt.task.registertask

Comment: This seems really silly and annoying. The error message is not descriptive at all! Thanks for the info though this saved me a ton of time.

Answer (score 3):

I also met this problem, i solved this by removing 
`grunt.registerTask('uglify', ['uglify']);`

before i solved this, i ran `grunt uglify -v` to check what happend.

I found it because that where you using this `grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');` ,it implicitly executes the `grunt.registerTask('uglify', ['uglify']);` ^_^